# Increase code font size when using jupyter notebook in presentation mode using RISE

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

I have a problem using jupyter notebook in presentation mode (I am using RISE).

The code font size is way too small compared to normal text size, it is not readable when showing it on a big screen:

[image]

I am really lost. If I increase the code size in the notebook, it only increases in the 'normal notebook' view. I also added a rise.css in my folder, but that changes nothing.
I also tried different themes, but the code is still too small, the size does not change at all.

Thanks for your support.

Kind Regards

Comment: Do the browser zoom settings improve the situation? Or .... Have you seen [here](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/255#issuecomment-597888568)? Granted that was before the change in the underlying tech of Jupyter Notebooks. It looks to me like you may be using Jupyter Notebook 7+ (if not JupyterLab).So don't be surprised if  none of those suggestions at the end may work. I know you say you are using RISE but don't give the version number of that or maybe more importantly in this case, the Jupyter interface you are specifically using in conjunction with RISE.